# How to conditionally render a Material UI dialog with the fade in/out animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I have a very simple app containing a list of users. When I click on one of the users I wish to show a dialog with various pieces of information about that user. I have tried to do this using Material UI's `Dialog` component using a couple of approaches however I run into issues either way.

I have a `UserDialog` component which takes a user as a prop and wraps Material UI's `Dialog` to include a bunch of user-specific things:

**UserDialog.jsx**

```
function UserDialog({ open, onClose, user }) {
  const title = `You are editing ${user.name}`
  const body = `This user is ${user.age} years old`

  const [name, setName] = React.useState(user.name)
  // Other stuff that references `user`.

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

## Approach 1 – Using the `open` prop

**UserList.jsx**

```
function UserList({ users }) {
  const [dialogUser, setDialogUser] = React.useState(null)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setDialogUser(user)}>
          {user.name}
        </button>
      ))}
      <UserDialog open={!!dialogUser} onClose={() => setDialogUser(null)} user={dialogUser} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

**Problem:** When `dialogUser` is set to `null` (e.g. initially) `UserDialog` crashes because it tries to access properties on `null`.

## Approach 2 – Conditional rendering

**UserList.jsx**

```
function UserList({ users }) {
  const [dialogUser, setDialogUser] = React.useState(null)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setDialogUser(user)}>
          {user.name}
        </button>
      ))}
      {dialogUser && <UserDialog open onClose={() => setDialogUser(null)} user={dialogUser} />}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

**Problem:** While this dialog fades in nicely, it abruptly disappears on close.

---

I know that it would theoretically work to wrap the content inside `UserDialog` inside a top-level `if (user)` block, but this isn't very nice and it also means weakening the prop type of the `user` prop which isn't ideal either.

Is there way to get the `Dialog` to fade in and out without having to conditionally render all of its content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you need to conditionnaly render the content :/

I suggest you use this approach:

```
function UserDialog({ open, onClose, user }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!!user && !data) {
      setData(user);
    }
  }, [user, data]);

  const title = `You are editing ${data?.name}`;
  const body = `This user is ${data?.age} years old`;

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{body}</p>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Great day !